# How to customize the default blur classes in TailwindCSS?

Tags: tailwind-css, blur

I'm trying to [customize the default blur](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/blur#customizing-your-theme) classes in TailwindCSS because I think their defaults are too much.

I know I can do something like:

```js
theme: {
  extend: {
    blur: {
      xs: '1px',
      sm: '2px',
      <blur>: '3px', // how to set this so I can just do class="blur" and it will give me filter: blur(3px)?
      md: '4px',
      lg: '5px',
      xl: '6px',
      '2xl': '8px',
      '3xl': '16px'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it looks so simple but I just have to do:

```js
DEFAULT: '3px'
```

And this should let me do something like

```html
<img src="/img/photo.jpg" class="blur" />
```

And the result would be a `filter: blur(3px)` on the image element.